# Variable in Parsley Error Message not updating

Tags: parsley.js

I have a form where I need to show an "expected value" for feedback on why the specific field is not validating.

This expected value changes with different input, like so:

```
var varOne = $('#id_iNeedToCheck').val() ;
var varTwo = $('#id_iNeedToCheck2').val() ;
var expectedValue = ( varOne / 28) + (varTwo / 10) + 8 ;

$('#id_iNeedToCheck').change(function(){
  return [varOne = $('#id_iNeedToCheck').val(),expectedValue = (varOne / 28) + (varTwo / 10) + 8] ;
});
```

The custom validation then looks like this:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('myValidator', {
   validateNumber: function(value) {
       if (value > expectedValue) {
         return value - expectedValue <= 7 ;
       }
       else {
         return expectedValue - value <= 7;
       }
   },
   requirementType: 'string',
   messages: {
       en: 'Your input differs too much from what we expect, we expect ' +  expectedValue + ', and your input can not be 7 more or 7 less than this value.'
   }
});
```

inside

```
   messages: {
       en: 'Your input differs too much from what we expect, we expect ' +  expectedValue + ', and your input can not be 7 more or 7 less than this value.'
   }
```

this value is never updated, as it seems this value is only parsed once, while the custom validator is constantly reparsed and works "as intended".

How do I make sure this message is updated/reparsed as "expectedValue" keeps changing?

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with interdepencencies is tricky. You could inspire yourself from [this example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/custom-validator-events.html).